# Why does arcpy.sa.Sample give TypeError: Sample() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst

I'm building a script where I'm taking a standardized CSV that one of our data processing packages consistently exports and turns it into a z-aware shp after running through Sample as well.  Along the way, I'm hitting a few roadblocks and could use any help I could get.  I've also included where I think I'll need to go afterwards in pseudocode.

```
#import modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

For testing I've been hardcoding these to place on disk.  They'll vary between projects though that I'm building into the tool.

```
#set in/out parameters
incsv = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
indem = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outshp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
spatialref = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
ftworkspacefldr = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)

#import xy events layer
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(table=incsv,in_x_field="ClickX",in_y_field="ClickY",out_layer="xylyr",spatial_reference=spatialref,in_z_field="#")

#maxe xy shp
outfc = ftworkspacefldr + "/XYContacts.shp"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features="xylyr",out_feature_class=outfc,config_keyword="#",spatial_grid_1="0",spatial_grid_2="0",spatial_grid_3="0")

#run sa.sample on shp
outxyztbl = ftworkspacefldr + "/FinalXYZContactsTable"
arcpy.sa.Sample(in_rasters=indem, in_location_data=outfc, resampling_type='NEAREST')
```

As I need to preserve the 50 other columns in the csv, I have to then join the output and copy over elevation.  The sample result only yields (OID,inputpointFID,x,y,sampled raster value)

```
##join output table to water depth field
#inzfield = str(indem)
#arcpy.AddField_management(outfc,"Elev_in_m","Double")
#arcpy.JoinField_management(outfc,"FID",outxyztbl,inzfield)

##copy sample z- result to new field in fc
#arcpy.CalculateField_management(outfc,"Elev_in_m",inzfield)

##make output table eventslayer (z-aware) and export to final shp
#arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(outxyztbl,in_x_field="ClickX",in_y_field="ClickY",out_layer=xyzlayer,spatial_reference=spatialref,in_z_field=inz)
```

My big current error is this (I'm not sure how sample doesn't work with all 3 arguments present?):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\01_Data\_ArcGISTools\Python Toolbox\Development     Workspace\swCSVtoshp.py", line 35, in <module>
arcpy.sa.Sample(in_rasters=indem, in_location_data=outfc, resampling_type='NEAREST')
TypeError: Sample() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Considering your inputs and specific requirements I'd not go with XY event layer and write the geometry directly - it's *really* not hard with an arcpy.da.insertCursor. See http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w0000000t000000 and note the examples. Your error is telling you that you haven't specified an output with the sample tool. BTW, with the tools you only need to specify the parameter if you're going out of order or skipping optional parameters otherwise just put them in in order.

Comment: It sounds like you are anticipating multiple problems so to fit with our focussed Q&A format I recommend that you treat each as a separate question to keep the code element to a snippet that works up to the point at which you are stuck.  I too think that arcpy.da cursors would be a better approach to this requirement.

Comment: What happened to your third GetParameterAsText?  i.e. where is arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)?  I suspect not retrieving it from the dialog will not trigger an error unless what you are getting `outshp` set to is something you did not intend.

Comment: Thanks all - Sample needed output I didn't put in.I'm going the xyevent layer route as the input CSV is only XY+50 other columns i need and the Sample output is just XYZ without the 50 columns.  I have to join and copy over the Z but in the end, going through arcpy.da.cursors would be better for assembling final FC.

Answer (score 1):

Per @Michael Miles-Stimson's comment - You are providing three parameters, just not the correct three parameters. You are missing the `out_table` parameter which is required. See the [Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000002v000000) which states the syntax is `Sample(in_rasters, in_location_data, out_table, {resampling_type})`.

I.e.

```
>>> from arcpy.sa import Sample
>>> Sample(in_rasters="test.tif",in_location_data="test.shp",out_table=r"C:\Temp\testresult.dbf",resampling_type='NEAREST')
<geoprocessing server result object object at 0x2EE36260>
>>> Sample("test.tif","test.shp",r"C:\Temp\testresult.dbf",resampling_type='NEAREST')
<geoprocessing server result object object at 0x2EE36260>
```

If you are missing one of the three required parameters (`in_rasters`,`in_location_data` or `out_table`) an exception will be raised:

```
>>> Sample("test.tif","test.shp",resampling_type='NEAREST')
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Sample() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of named parameters like this:

```
arcpy.sa.Sample(in_rasters=indem, in_location_data=outfc, resampling_type='NEAREST')
```

try it without:

```
arcpy.sa.Sample(indem, outfc, 'NEAREST')
```

Comment: The problem is that he *hasn't supplied an output*, just input raster, points to sample and a resampling method. The tool needs to know where to put the output table!

Comment: The error message implies the function isn't configured to take named arguments, only positional ones.

Comment: That's possible, the error message indicates that it's got three parameters but might have issues resolving them. I've only used named arguments to include an optional parameter without having to do strings like *"","","","","value"*; it's clearer what optional parameter you're specifying if you name it. That aside, the tool still needs to know the output or it's not going to work.